# how to return random string Arrray Java

Tags: java

I am very new to Java, so this could seem too easy for most people....Is this completely wrong?
My question is how to write a method `selectRandom(String[] names)`,
which returns a randomly selected name from the given array.

Each name should be selected with equal probability.

```
public static String selectRandom(String[] names)    
{    
    String num = names[0]; 
    int[]newArray = new int[names.length];
    for(int i =0; i<names.length;i++)
    {
      Random r = new Random();
      int ranNum= r.nextInt(names.length)+1;
      num = names[ranNum];
    }
    return num;  
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have a loop there. Just select the random index and return the corresponding string.

Comment: The steps: select a number randomly that is less than array length, the return the array element? Can you translate this to code?

Comment: i think the main problem here is not how to get a random. since OP mentioned **Each name should be selected with equal probability.** I think he needs a uniformed random function. I don't think Random in java core library is uniformed.

Comment: @Kent `int java.util.Random.nextInt(int n): Returns a new pseudo-random integer value which is uniformly distributed between 0 (inclusively) and n (exclusively)`

Comment: @pankar checked the doc again.  **Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)..**  u r right. thx. I think I was abit mixing up with real-random...

Comment: In order to demonstrate the uniformity of the `nextInt` method [check this out](http://ideone.com/N3LGG). For 100000 iterations each of the numbers 0-9 is (almost) evenly chosen (~10000 times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static String selectRandom(String[] names)    
{    
      Random r = new Random();
      int ranNum= r.nextInt(names.length);
      return names[ranNum];

}
```

You don't need most of the codes inside your method. Maybe you should try something like this?

Comment: it may generate NullPointerException too.

Comment: @Russell Gutierrez Can you please tell me how can I choose a random string value from an array and also I want some other string every time. I mean if I don't want to repeat the same  string value, what's modification I need in this code .

Answer (score 5):

You can simply generate a random number up to the array size, and get the value at that index.

```
public static String selectRandom(String[] names) {
    if (name != null && names.length > 0) {
        Random r = new Random();
        return names[r.nextInt(names.length)];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you should add null check also otherwise `if (names.length > 0)` it may populate nullpointer exception.

Comment: @Vulcan Can you please tell me how can I choose a random string value from an array and also I want some other string every time. I mean if I don't want to repeat the same  string value, what's modification I need in this code .

Comment: @Kunu Create another array of Strings (or booleans) and keep track of which Strings you've randomly picked already.

Comment: @Vulcan I was also thinking about that, but thought it would be wise to ask others first so if there any direct method exist in Random function I could do it easily. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly choose an index and return the corresponding `String` in `names`. There is a [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to do get random numbers in java. Also check [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method.

```
public static String selectRandom(String[] names)    
{    
   Random rand = new Random();
   int index = rand.nextInt(names.length);
   return names[index];
}
```